# GetMenuItemInfo Error 1456

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to enumerate and subsequently remove all items from a provided hMenu using the code shown below.  For many of the items, however, I'm getting a 1456 error, indicating that the menu item was not found, but I have no idea why.

For my particular menu, the call to GetMenuItemCount() returns 34, which I assume means there are 34 menu items available to iterate.  Apparently, this isn't the case, as the iteration stops producing valid menu item info at item 18 of 34.

Here's my code:

```
private IEnumerable<string> EnumerateItems(IntPtr hMenu)
{
    var count = User32.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        MENUITEMINFO_I mif = new MENUITEMINFO_I();
        mif.fMask = User32.MIIM_STRING;
        mif.fType = User32.MFT_STRING;
        mif.dwTypeData = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, i, true, mif);
        if (!res)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Get String Info Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            continue;
        }

        mif.cch++;
        mif.dwTypeData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)(mif.cch * 2));
        try
        {
            res = GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, i, true, mif);
            if (!res)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Get Caption Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                continue;
            }
            string caption = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mif.dwTypeData);
            if (res)
            {
                yield return caption;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mif.dwTypeData);
        }

        if (!DeleteMenu(hMenu, i, MF_BYPOSITION))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Delete Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Exp&and
<no caption>
<no caption>
Restore previous &versions
KDiff3
&Pin to Start
Add &to "Archive.rar"
Compress to "Archive.rar" and email
<no caption>
{A4756F80-4AE7-4A1F-A776-F5E9D9B04406}
{A4756F80-4AE7-4A1F-A776-F5E9D9B04406}
&Copy
Create &shortcut
<no caption>
{A4756F80-4AE7-4A1F-A776-F5E9D9B04406}
P&roperties
{A4756F80-4AE7-4A1F-A776-F5E9D9B04406}
{A4756F80-4AE7-4A1F-A776-F5E9D9B04406}
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
Get String Info Error: 1456
```

Leaving my menu including the following menu items, which I really want to remove:
[image]

EDIT:

Including the MENUITEMINFO as requested:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class MENUITEMINFO_I
{
    public int cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public uint fType;
    public uint fState;
    public uint wID;
    public IntPtr hSubMenu;
    public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
    public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
    public IntPtr dwItemData;
    public IntPtr dwTypeData;
    public uint cch;
    public IntPtr hbmpItem;

    public MENUITEMINFO_I()
    {
        cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that everything works as expected for the first 18 items, and I'm testing on a Win 10 box.

EDIT 2:

I revised the code to always use element 0, since I am deleting menu items on each pass, and now iteration is working as expected.  However, I am left with some menu items that don't want to be deleted.  See below:

[image]

DeleteMenu is not producing an error for these items, but I need them to go away.

Thanks!

Comment: *Note that you must set the cbSize member to sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) before calling this function.*

Comment: Yes, I'm setting it in the ctor to the MENUITEM_I class (with struct layout).

Comment: Ok, so now we really need to see `MENUITEM_I` How is the struct defined?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: So I just scrolled your code down to the bottom, and noticed you are calling `DeleteMenu` on every iteration. Say you delete item 0 from the menu. The item that was item 1 will become the new item 0. But next time around, you're querying item 1 - skipping over one item.

Comment: Good catch!  I switched to use element 0 on every iteration, and now I can enumerate all the items.  But DeleteMenu isn't deleting all the items, some items remain after deleting without any errors.  See my further update above.

Comment: @odinhaus Hi, Could you please tell me how you got hMenu for right-click?